# What does this Javascript Sign up Code do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

It is related to an ajax/jquery 1.3.2 based sign up form. I want to learn how to make this and use jquery in general by understanding the code/syntax line by line.

Can someone explain what this code is trying to accomplish and how it does so line by line?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        // Email Signup
        $("form#sub_name").submit(function() {        
             var dataStr = $("#UserEmail").val();
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "signup.php",
                 data : {UserEmail: dataStr},
                 success: function(del){
                     $("#signup-success").html(del);
                     $("#signup-success").fadeIn();
                     $('#signup-success').fadeOut(10000);
                 }
             });
             return false;
         });                             
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: One thing it does is use up horizontal page real estate :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code explained in the comments.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){  // run this code on page load
        // Email Signup
        $("form#sub_name").submit(function() {   // activate on form submit for sign in
                                                 // the id of the form is sub_name     
             var dataStr = $("#UserEmail").val();  // get the email address from an                                 
                                                   // input field with ID UserEmail
             $.ajax({                            // use and ajax call to signup.php 
                                                 // using POST method
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "signup.php",             
                 data : {UserEmail: dataStr},    // The parameter UserEmail is passed.
                 success: function(del){         // this part displays the success
                     $("#signup-success").html(del);  // probably a div with id signup-success
                     $("#signup-success").fadeIn();  // is faded in and 
                     $('#signup-success').fadeOut(10000);  // removed after 10 seconds
                 }
             });
             return false;
         });                             
    });
```

Comment: Good stuff. If the $jQuery.ajax call doesn't make a lot of sense to you, read [the documentation for it](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/); particularly the section for `success`.